# Selenium 2 with liferay

Tags: selenium, liferay, selenium-webdriver

I am using Selenium 2 to test a web-based system that uses Liferay portlets.

Some links have post actions. Once I click on the link it should start some action such as open a URL and/or open the portlets on that URL.

I did a test case with java to open a URL. BUT all the portlets are closed.

Is there any setup or configuration for Liferay that can take care of this?

If not, can any one help me with my issue?

Thank you

Comment: I don't understand what you mean with "all the portlets are closed"? Selenium is basically simulating the browser, so given proper authoring it shouldn't do anything different than the actual browser.

Answer (score 1):

Liferay Portal UI testing cannot be done using opensource selenium. They have their own implementation of Selenium over for Liferay portal UI. Please find more details here

http://www.liferay.com/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Selenium+Testing

Answer (score 0):

Actually, Liferay Portal UI testing CAN be done using opensource Selenium, i've done it. You don't need to use their implementation.